# comment section doesn't save comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I made a comment section in a rails app but when I post a comment and the page gets reloaded, the comment is not saved. I get no error though.

I have this in routes.rb:

```
resources :analyses, only: [:index, :create, :show, :destroy, :update] do
    collection do
      post :destroy_multiple
      get :start_multiple
      post :custom_create
    end

    member do
      resources :comparisons, only: :show, param: :document_id
    end

      resources :comments
  end
```

and then:

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :body, type: String
  embedded_in :analysis
  belongs_to :analysis
end
```

while in:

```
class Analysis
  embeds_many :comments
```

then:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @analysis = Analysis.find(params[:analysis_id])
    @comment = @analysis.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
    redirect_to analyses_path(@analysis)
  end

  def destroy
    @analysis = Analysis.find(params[:analysis_id])
    @comment = @analysis.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to analyses_path(@analysis)
  end
end
```

_comment.haml:

```
%p= comment.name
%p= comment.body
%p= time_ago_in_words(comments,created_at)
%p
  = link_to 'Delete',[comment.analysis, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?' }
```

and _form.haml:

```
= form_for([@analysis,@analysis.comments.build]) do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    = f.label :body
    %br/
    = f.text_area :body
  %br/
  %p
    = f.submit
```

and in analyses/show.html.haml I put:

```
%br/
= @analysis.comments.count
Comments
= render @analysis.comments
%h5
Add a Comment:
= render 'comments/form'
```

did I make a mistake anywhere that I don't see the comments or do I have to do it all differently?

EDIT:

```
Started POST "/analyses/2d1234c6543bca03s444des7/comments" for **** at 2019-02-23 16:28:09 +0100
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***==", "comment"=>{"name"=>"fefwefew", "body"=>"dfwedew"} "commit"=>"Create Comment", "analysis_id"=>"2d1234c6543bca03s444des7"}
MONGODB | localhost:80000 | ***.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"analyses", "filter"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('2d1234c6543bca03s444des7')}}
MONGODB | localhost:80000 | ***.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.008967s
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/analyses.2d1234c6543bca03s444des7
Completed 302 Found in 47ms
```

Comment: Use pry and inspect what's in the create method in CommentsController

Comment: Whould you share the logs regarding to submission of comment creation?

Comment: @zeitnot I will add that in my initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```rb
  def create
    @analysis = Analysis.find(params[:analysis_id])
    @comment = @analysis.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to analyses_path(@analysis)
  end

  private 

  def comment_params 
   params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
  end
```

Comment: Just try `@comment = Comment.create!(analysis: @analysis, **comment_params)`

Comment: I get: `wrong argument type String (expected Symbol)`

Comment: Fist: `@comment = @analysis.comments.build(comment_params)` and then `@comment.save!`

Comment: I get now: `message:
  Validation of Comment failed.
summary:
  The following errors were found: Analysis can't be blank
resolution:
  Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.`

Comment: Just remove `belongs_to :analysis` from `Comment` class because `Comment` is already embedded in `Analysis`.

Comment: thank you, it worked! Just if you can tell me why isn't the `created_at` not working here : %p= time_ago_in_words(comment,created_at) , it says `undefined local variable or method 'created_at'`

Comment: Include Timestamp module to your `Comment` class like `include Mongoid::Timestamps`

Comment: did that but have the same error still, and also tried to put `set_created_at` as shown in the ruby documentation, didn't work either.

Comment: In the `Analysis` model put this: `embeds_many :comments, cascade_callbacks: true`

Comment: Still have the same error: `undefined local variable or method 'created_at' for #<#<Class:0x00...` at `%p= time_ago_in_words(comment, created_at)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188938/discussion-between-zeitnot-and-luftgekuhltlover).